# Sort Merged Cells (Excel) - Adapt Code to sort on different column

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to sort a range (based on F column) that someone has applied merged cells.

(my merged cells)
ABCD | E | F | GH

I found an excellent response to my problem, but I need to change the column in the orignial response ([[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549570/sorting-an-excel-table-that-contains-merged-cells#*=*][1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549570/sorting-an-excel-table-that-contains-merged-cells#_=_][1]))

The code is sorting on the A column (bubble sort) and my problem requires to be sorted on F column (also the B column for another range, but if I learn how to change in one place, I can figure out how to change the other).

I have stepped through it many times and I believe this line requires a change here (maybe colStartIndex + 6)

```
Range(Cells(rowStartIndex, colStartIndex), Cells(tempCal, colStartIndex)).Copy Destination:=Range(Cells(tempRowIndex, tempColIndex), Cells(tempRowIndex + tempCal, tempColIndex))
```

and also here (compares the bubble sort to temp list)

```
Dim orgRange, tempRange As Long
     For iIndex = 0 To rowCount - 2 Step 1
        rowIndex = iIndex + tempRowIndex
        tempRange = Cells(rowIndex, tempColIndex)
        'MsgBox (tempRange)
            For jIndex = 0 To rowCount - 2 Step 1
                rowIndex = jIndex + rowStartIndex
                orgRange = Cells(rowIndex, colStartIndex)

                If tempRange = orgRange Then
                    'MsgBox ("Match Found : \n (tempRange,orgRange) : (" & tempRange & "," & orgRange & ")")

                   Range(Cells(rowIndex, colStartIndex), Cells(rowIndex, colStartIndex + colCount - 1)).Copy Destination:=Cells(tempFinalRowIndex + iIndex, tempFinalColIndex)
              End If
          Next jIndex
       Next iIndex
```

This is the entire Sub Procedure as posted in the original response. I have made some extra comments as a learning aid for myself. I understand all the code with the exception of changing the sort column.

```
Private Sub QuickAscending_Click()
Dim myRange As Range        'variable to hold the Named Range
Dim rowCount As Long        'variable to hold the Number of Rows in myRange
Dim colCount As Long        'variable to hold the Number of Columns in myRange
Dim rowStartIndex As Long   'variable to hold the Starting Row index of myRange
Dim colStartIndex As Long   'variable to hold the Starting Col index of myRange
Dim iIndex As Long          'Variable used for iteration
Dim jIndex As Long          'Variable used for iteration
Dim current As Long         'used in bubble sort to hold the value of the current jIndex item
Dim currentPlusOne As Long          'used in bubble sort to hold the value of the  jIndex+1 item
Dim rowIndex As Long
Dim tempRowIndex, tempColIndex As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Set myRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("SortRangeValue")
rowStartIndex = myRange.Row
colStartIndex = myRange.Column
colCount = myRange.Columns.Count
rowCount = myRange.Rows.Count
Dim tempCal As Long
tempCal = rowCount + rowStartIndex - 1

''''''this sets the process to bubble sort. Copies array (first column) to temp location and then loops to bubble sort
tempRowIndex = 6
tempColIndex = 200
Range(Cells(rowStartIndex, colStartIndex), Cells(tempCal, colStartIndex)).Copy Destination:=Range(Cells(tempRowIndex, tempColIndex), Cells(tempRowIndex + tempCal, tempColIndex))
     For iIndex = 0 To rowCount - 3 Step 1
        For jIndex = 0 To rowCount - iIndex - 3 Step 1
            rowIndex = jIndex + tempRowIndex
            current = Cells(rowIndex, tempColIndex)
            currentPlusOne = Cells(rowIndex + 1, tempColIndex)
            If current > currentPlusOne Then
            Cells(rowIndex, tempColIndex) = currentPlusOne
            Cells(rowIndex + 1, tempColIndex) = current
            End If
       Next jIndex
     Next iIndex

     Dim tempFinalRowIndex, tempFinalColIndex As Long
     tempFinalRowIndex = 6
     tempFinalColIndex = 201

''''''This part compares the bubble sort and copies the row to the temp location
     Dim orgRange, tempRange As Long
     For iIndex = 0 To rowCount - 2 Step 1
        rowIndex = iIndex + tempRowIndex
        tempRange = Cells(rowIndex, tempColIndex)
        'MsgBox (tempRange)
            For jIndex = 0 To rowCount - 2 Step 1
                rowIndex = jIndex + rowStartIndex
                orgRange = Cells(rowIndex, colStartIndex)

                If tempRange = orgRange Then
                    'MsgBox ("Match Found : \n (tempRange,orgRange) : (" & tempRange & "," & orgRange & ")")

                   Range(Cells(rowIndex, colStartIndex), Cells(rowIndex, colStartIndex + colCount - 1)).Copy Destination:=Cells(tempFinalRowIndex + iIndex, tempFinalColIndex)
              End If
          Next jIndex
       Next iIndex

    ''Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ''''''This copies the temp last back to the original range
    Range(Cells(tempFinalRowIndex, tempFinalColIndex), Cells(tempFinalRowIndex + rowCount - 2, tempFinalColIndex + colCount - 1)).Copy Destination:=Range(Cells(rowStartIndex, colStartIndex), Cells(rowStartIndex + rowCount - 2, colStartIndex + colCount - 1))
    ''''deletes the temp rows
    Range(Cells(tempFinalRowIndex - 1, tempFinalColIndex), Cells(tempFinalRowIndex + rowCount - 2, tempFinalColIndex + colCount - 1)).Delete
    Range(Cells(tempRowIndex, tempColIndex), Cells(tempRowIndex + rowCount - 2, tempColIndex)).Delete
End Sub
```

Thank you for any help!
Brent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to adjust the below code to use my required columns.

```
Range(Cells(rowStartIndex, colStartIndex + 5), Cells(tempCal, colStartIndex + 5))
```

and also

```
 orgRange = Cells(rowIndex, colStartIndex + 5)
```